# Excel: Copying an entire row based on match works in Google Docs but not in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an image of what I am trying to achieve

[image]

The formula I am putting into E13 is:

```
=INDEX(A1:E4,MATCH(C6,B1:B4,0),0)
```

This just gives me the end column value for that row, not the entire row.

However if I do the same in Google Docs, it brings me back the entire row as desired.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uvlUJj1F5R4ZLDQ7dbktxP1gdMH_ipw31OGru5SkNsE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel is different than Google Sheets, Excel requires a formula in each cell that an output is expected.

Put

```
=INDEX($A$1:$E$4,MATCH($C6,$B$1:$B$4,0),COLUMN(A:A))
```

In E13 and copy over 5 columns and down 4 and you will get what you want.

Comment: I was basing it off this which seems to do the trick. https://exceljet.net/formula/lookup-entire-row

Comment: Yes you can use that too, but you need to array enter the formula. You need to go to the link under `Multi-cell array formula` and follow those instructions.  You will still be adding the formula to all the cells just as an array formula.  I find it easier to work with individual instead of Multi-cell array formulas.